# FreeIPA SSH keys not working with Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, freeipa, keys

I have FreeIPA setup and its working fine so far with Centos7, Rocky8 and Rocky 9 machines. Users can SSH into machines using their SSH keys.

Yesterday I added a Ubuntu machine and it wont let me SSH in with my key. It will however let me SSH in with my password.

There is clearly something different in the way that the FreeIPA client gets installed on Ubuntu. Some setting must be preventing the use of SSH keys. This is what I get:

[image]

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: New information: It works as expected with Ubuntu 18.04 but does not work for Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

Comment: What's your sshd config? What do your logs say? What does `ssh -vvv` say?

Answer (score 1):

This is now resolved. The problem was AWS related. In newer versions of Ubuntu images (20.04 upwards) in AWS, ssh via key files reaches out to something called ec2 instance connect. This bypasses FreeIPA and so you then cant SSH in using your key file.

The following file is the problem:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/ec2-instance-connect.conf
```

To fix it use the following steps.

Create an ssh.service/d directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d
```

Create a blank file. This file will take priority over the other bad file:

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/ec2-instance-connect.conf
```

After making such a change reload the daemon:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart the sshd service:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

You should now be able to SSH in using key files via your FreeIPA server.